# Evaluate string giving boolean expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eval, boolean-logic

I have a string that contains Boolean logic something like:

```
var test = "(true)&&(false)&&!(true||true)"
```

What is a good way to evaluate this string in JavaScript to get the boolean value of false in this case

1. I know we could use eval() or new Function().. - but is that a safe approach?
2. I am guessing the other option would be to write a custom parser. Being a fairly new person to JS, would that be a lot of effort? I could not find any examples of parsers for Boolean logic expressions
3. Any other alternatives?

Comment: What is the source of `"(true)&&(false)&&!(true||true)"` ?

Comment: I am parsing the response from the server and building that string based on some logic

Comment: You could use server returned data as bool after applying logic. Why do u convert it to string?

Comment: It's safe to use `eval` _only_ when you can guarantee the source isn't malicious and doesn't contain an issue. If you're the one building the string and you've written your code to guarantee only a boolean string is constructed, it should be fine.

Comment: If the syntax was like `"(1)&(0)&!(1||1)"` (all tokens are only 1 character), it would be easier to parse

Comment: Using `new Function()` doesn't make sense because you don't actually want a function, you just want the result of the expression.

Comment: If i could make the string "(1)&(0)&!(1||1)", how would that make parsing easier?

Comment: @nnnnnn It can be used like `new Function("return " + boolStr)()`. Of course `eval(boolStr)` would be better. Both can run arbitrary JS, so avoid them if the source is not trusted.

Comment: @akoy Because the length of all tokens are 1 character. It wouldn't be incredibly more easy, but a little bit.

Comment: I don't understand... Can your server respond in more "common" ways like JSON or smth. so you can compare your vars without using `eval`? OR if the whole string is returned by server, why can't server check this condition by itself and respond with a single `true`/`false` for a whole condition?

Comment: @Oriol - Yes. My point wasn't that you *can't* achieve this via `new Function()`, I just meant that that is a pointlessly complicated alternative to `eval()`. On the one character 1|0 issue, you could just use .replace() before parsing...

Comment: if your server is returning as "(true)&&(false)&&!(true||true)" then would It not be possible for you to directly evaluate the whole expression on serve and return only the result as true or false?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you can guarantee it to be safe, I think you could use eval.

Maybe by treating it before doing an eval?

```
var test = "(true)&&(false)&&!(true||true)" 

var safe = test.replace(/true/ig, "1").replace(/false/ig, "0");

var match = safe.match(/[0-9&!|()]*/ig);

if(match) {
   var result = !!eval(match[0]);
}
```

Comment: Cannot be used if a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP) has disabled code evaluation though.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript has a ternary operator you could use:**

```
var i = result ? 1 : 0;
```

Here, result is **`Boolean`** value either `True` or `False`.

So, Your question will be something like that after this operation.

```
(1)&(0)&!(1||1)
```

I hope you can better evaluate now this Boolean logic.

Answer (score 1):

you can use eval, 
Eg: eval("(true)&&(false)&&!(true||true)");

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function processExpression(expr)
{
  while (expr.indexOf("(" ) != -1 )
  {
    expr = expr.replace(/\([\w|]+\)/g, function(matched){ return processBrace(matched)});
  }
  return expr = processBrace( "(" + expr + ")" );
}
function processBrace(str)
{
    return str.substring(1).slice(0,-1).split(/(?=&|\|)/).map(function(value,index,arr){ 
        if ( index != 0 && index%2 == 0 ) { return arr[index-1] + value } else if(index==0){return value;} else {return ""}
    }).filter(function(val){return val.length > 0}).reduce(function(prev,current){
        var first = Boolean(prev);
        var operator = current.substring(0,2);
        var operand = current.substring(2); 
        while ( operand.indexOf("!") != -1 )
        {
           var boolval = operand.match(/\w+/)[0] == "false"; //flip the value by comparing it with false
           var negations = operand.match(/\W+/)[0];
           operand = negations.substring(1) + boolval;
        }
        var second = operand == "true";
        var output = operator == "&&" ? (first && second) : (first || second); 
        return output;
    });
}
```

DEMO

```js
    function processExpression(expr)
    {
      while (expr.indexOf("(" ) != -1 )
      {
     expr = expr.replace(/\([\w|]+\)/g, function(matched){ return processBrace(matched)});
      }
      return expr = processBrace( "(" + expr + ")" );
    }
    function processBrace(str)
    {
     return str.substring(1).slice(0,-1).split(/(?=&|\|)/).map(function(value,index,arr){ 
      if ( index != 0 && index%2 == 0 ) { return arr[index-1] + value } else if(index==0){return value;} else {return ""}
     }).filter(function(val){return val.length > 0}).reduce(function(prev,current){
      var first = Boolean(prev);
      var operator = current.substring(0,2);
      var operand = current.substring(2); 
      while ( operand.indexOf("!") != -1 )
      {
         var boolval = operand.match(/\w+/)[0] == "false"; //flip the value by comparing it with false
         var negations = operand.match(/\W+/)[0];
         operand = negations.substring(1) + boolval;
      }
      var second = operand == "true";
      var output = operator == "&&" ? (first && second) : (first || second); 
      return output;
     });
    }


var example1 = "(true)&&(false)&&!(true||true)";
document.body.innerHTML += example1 + " -- " + processExpression(example1);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try using**   `"".match()` in ternary operator condition

```
"(true)&&(true)&&!(true||true)".match(/false/ig)?false:true
```

Comment: There's a `!` Symbol i the statement

Comment: Thanks for your comment but downgrading the comment on your own thinking is not the right way, kindly i request you to be positive and don't downgrade my comment.
Actually I don't write ```!``` in my comment, I just copied it from the questioner. Thanks